# How to indicate the ios app must be installed on iphone ,not ipod and not ipad

Tags: iphone

I want to develope an app which only work on iphone,not ipad and not ipod.How I should indicate this case in info.plist or xcode project setting?

Comment: Why would you want to exclude hardware that is otherwise capable of running your software?

Answer (score 0):

Under target device family in xcode project but you cannot avoid iPod devices.

Answer (score 0):

If you require specific hardware features such as a camera or 3g, you can add the requirement to the info.plist for the app, however, the app will still run in devices such as the ipad (at iPhone 1x resolution) if the iPad has the appropriate hardware.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/BuildTimeConfiguration/BuildTimeConfiguration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW10

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "you can't."

What you can do is specify specific bits of hardware that you need to operate, for example a camera or new enough 3G graphics capabilities. You use the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` flag in the apps `Info.plist`. More in the [documentation here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/RuntimeEnvironment/RuntimeEnvironment.html).